# How to re-parent an old revision to a different branch?

Tags: svn, revision-history

We have a project with a few thousand files that has source control history going back nearly two decades.

<kbd>Revision 1</kbd> → <kbd>Revision 2</kbd> → <kbd>Revision 3</kbd> ... <kbd>Revision 18352</kbd>

And them someone wanted to take a copy of the current development for another customer. But rather than make a [`copy`](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.copy.html), they simply [`add`ed](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.add.html) them to a new folder in SVN - losing all history:

| Customer A | Customer B |
| --- | --- |
| <kbd>Revision 1</kbd> (2005) | <kbd>Revision 18432</kbd> (2018) |
| <kbd>Revision 2</kbd> | <kbd>Revision 18421</kbd> |
| <kbd>Revision 3</kbd> | <kbd>Revision 18589</kbd> |
| <kbd>Revision 219</kbd> | <kbd>Revision 18968</kbd> |
| <kbd>Revision 17768</kbd> |  |
| <kbd>Revision 18352</kbd> |  |

When it was time to create another branch for another customer, i made sure to create a `copy` of the **Customer B** branch - so that i had as much code history as possible:

| Customer A | Customer B | Customer C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| <kbd>Revision 1</kbd> (2005) | <kbd>Revision 18432</kbd> (2018) |  |
| <kbd>Revision 2</kbd> | <kbd>Revision 18421</kbd> |  |
| <kbd>Revision 3</kbd> | <kbd>Revision 18589</kbd> |  |
| <kbd>Revision 219</kbd> | <kbd>Revision 18968</kbd> |  |
| <kbd>Revision 17768</kbd> | copied to new branch→ | <kbd>Revision20972</kbd> (2022) |
| <kbd>Revision 18352</kbd> |  | <kbd>Revision20973</kbd> |
|  |  | <kbd>Revision20975</kbd> |
|  |  | <kbd>Revision21006</kbd> |
|  |  | <kbd>Revision21248</kbd> |

But the code i'm working on is now missing a decade and a half of source history.

### So the question is

How do i re-parent <kbd>Revision 18432</kbd> in **Customer B** branch to retroactively say it was a copy of <kbd>Revision 18352</kbd> in **Customer A** branch:

| Customer A | Customer B | Customer C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| <kbd>Revision 1</kbd> (2005) |  |  |
| <kbd>Revision 2</kbd> |  |  |
| <kbd>Revision 3</kbd> |  |  |
| <kbd>Revision 219</kbd> |  |  |
| <kbd>Revision 17768</kbd> |  |  |
| <kbd>Revision 18352</kbd> |  |  |
| ⬑ parent | <kbd>Revision 18432</kbd> (2018) |  |
|  | <kbd>Revision 18421</kbd> |  |
|  | <kbd>Revision 18589</kbd> |  |
|  | <kbd>Revision 18968</kbd> |  |
|  | ⬑ parent | <kbd>Revision20972</kbd> (2022) |
|  |  | <kbd>Revision20973</kbd> |
|  |  | <kbd>Revision20975</kbd> |
|  |  | <kbd>Revision21006</kbd> |
|  |  | <kbd>Revision21248</kbd> |
|  |  | <kbd>Revision20975</kbd> |
|  |  | <kbd>Revision21006</kbd> |
|  |  | <kbd>Revision21248</kbd> |

Comment: I think that you can create a new branch to replace CustomerC out of CustomerA and merge from CustomerB and CustomerC into this new branch. I.e., `svn copy` from CustomerA to create a new branch, then merge changes from CustomerB and CustomerC into this branch. Continue your work on the new branch. I don't have access to SVN client (I'm on vacation without access to a computer), but I believe that this solution will help you.

Comment: @bahrep But i think merging changes would only bring merge the "current" version, and not maintain all the history built-up in **B** and **C**